# Is it a way to disable function and force built-ins execution in bash

Tags: bash, function

I am writing a wrapper function for the `test` built-in, that suppose to print out return value after each test:

```
# function test() { test $*; echo $?; }
```

Of course when I run it, it runs recursively, calling itself each time when `test` is reached, because built-in list is checked after a function list. Is it a way to restrict search to built-ins? For example prepend it with some magic string?

Comment: Can't you rename wrapper function ?

Comment: `$ help builtin`

Comment: @DigvijayS, no, I want to wrap a real test built-in

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are aptly named magic strings, `builtin` and `command`:

```
$ function test() { command test $*; echo $?; }   # Looks for test in PATH.
$ test foo
0
$ test 1 -gt 2
1
$ function test() { builtin test $*; echo $?; }   # Uses builtin.
$ test 1 -gt 0
0
```

The `command` way has the advantage that it is POSIX, while `builtin` is not.